# Hiding the Command Console from a MFC dialog application

Tags: command-line, mfc, dialog, system

I have a MFC dialog based application in which I use ::system() function to physically open a text file. When I do it the command console also opens. How can I **hide the command console so that it doesn't pop up when I'm opening the text file?**

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` instead of `::system`. `::system` will cause the shell (cmd.exe on windows) to be launched which is why the console window is displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I used ShellExecute() and it works fine :)

Comment: Can you pls give me a example on this , i am also facing the same issue.